# Set Execution time to several Statements in Java

Tags: java

I need to set execution time to several statements in java. Once it couldn't be done, then I need to neglect those statements and execute the program normally. I don't want to repeat those statements again and again. Is there some way to code like try and catch event?

```
try{

//some statements to execute in a given time.

}catch(){

    // if it couldn't be done

}
```

I tried this code.

```
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = 
    new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    sendTokenSock.receive(receivePacket);
    sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());

    rcvd = receivePacket.getAddress().getHostName();
    System.out.println("RECEIVED:"+sentence);
```

I want to wait for a datagram for given time or leave without closing socket.

Comment: In your code is nothing which has anything to do with your question. Please include the code you have already tried.

Comment: You mean you want to make sure some statements don't take longer than N milliseconds?

Comment: Ok, I added some statements of the code. Yes I need to make sure the time or leave without executing.

Answer (score 3):

Execute your statements in a `Thread` and then let your code `join` on this thread with a timeout:

```
Thread runnableThread = new Thread(yourRunnable);
runnableThread.start();
runnableThread.join(executionTimeout);
```

To check if the thread finished with a timeout, call `Thread.isAlive()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, But i need to do this without using threads. Is there any way to do this without threads?

Answer (score 0):

What you ask cannot reliably be done.  If the statements you want to time are coded to cooperate with the effort, however, then something along these lines could work:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // statements to time
    }
});

t.run();
try {
    t.join(/* millis to wait */);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // The thread was unexpectedly interrupted
}
if (t.isAlive()) {
    t.interrupt();
    // it couldn't be done
} else {
    // it ran within time
}
```

The problem with that is that `t.interrupt()` is not certain to actually make the thread stop executing, much less make it stop in a timely manner.  It is possible to write the task being run in a way that makes that more likely, but if you try that approach with general code the you're just crossing your fingers and hoping.

Comment: Great! I got your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I wrote the program of what I think you meant,if I understood wrong please correct me.

```
 //let's say you have to wait for 42 miliseconds
 try{
    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //do your thing;
    long y = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread.sleep(42-y-x);
 }
 catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```